Why are no new sheets created although the code manages to run?
#Load master worksheet to paste the newly splitted fixings
master_file = "output.xlsm"
master_si = load_workbook(master_file, keep_vba=True)

#Load nicer_ws, then read to become data frame !!!
nicer_split = pd.read_excel(old_murex, sheet_name='nicer_WS')
print('Initial nicer_split: ')
print(nicer_split)

# Ensure 'Dates' is a string (or datetime if preferred)
nicer_split['Dates'] = nicer_split['Dates'].astype(str)

# Split the DataFrame into multiple DataFrames based on 'Dates'
dfads = {datete: group for datete, group in nicer_split.groupby('Dates')}

# Access individual DataFrames
for date, dataframe in dfads.items():
    print(f"DataFrame for Dates {date}:")
    print(dataframe)
    print("\n")


#writing the new dfs into the excel sheet
with pd.ExcelWriter(master_file, engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:
    for date, dataframe in dfads.items():
        dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f'{date}', startcol=2, index=False)


#save it into the master SI file
master_si.save(master_file)
print("Dataframes have been written!")


The dataframe as some dates (sensitive data), i want to split the dataframe into smaller dataframes of each date. I have managed to do this part over here, but when i try to run the bottom part of the code (the with statement there), it manages to run , but no new sheets were made in the excel workbook.
A side problem, when the code runs for the first time after restarting the jupyter kernel, it picks up an empty data frame. But when I go to the excel file and make minor tweaks (eg. change sheet tab colour, adjust column size, etc), the code is able to pick up the excel sheet and do the splitting. Not sure what seems to be the error, thanks in advance!

maybe it's the mode='a' (append)?

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Not a problem with mode. However you open the Excel file with Openpyxl master_si = load_workbook(master_file, keep_vba=True) Then write your dataframes to that Excel file with to_excel loop. Then overwrite that Excel file at the end with the Openpyxl loaded copy which has no changes made to it, master_si.save(master_file). So the end result is the Excel file will be exactly the same as it was at the start, and the last print statement is a lie.

If you are using Pandas then Pandas uses Openpyxl or whatever module the engine has set. You do not (and given your issue should not) open the file first in the other module. However given the file is XLSM you are going to have a problem using Pandas

@moken Your diagnosis is spot on! But are you sure a XLSM is a problem (I've tried it and it worked fine)? Opening the pd.ExcelWriter with the kwarg engine_kwargs={'keep_vba': True} should keep the VBA part intact.

@Timus It's from what I remember, but I'm not necessarily up to date with working with Pandas and XLSMs. I expected that if he wasn't overwriting his Pandas created Excel file he would have ended up with an XLSX file (with xlsm extension) instead. However your suggestion with setting engine_kwargs= is probably the way to go now to avoid that.

@timus used engine_kwargs={'keep_vba': True} and my code works now, thank you guys!
